# REACT Duplicated Key Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently get this duplicated key warning "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key". However, I am unsure where this duplication of key comes from. I am using the fileData id as my key which should be unique as it is firebase generated id. Therefore, I am not so sure what is happening behind here.

Here are my codes below and the warning I get.

MultimediaDetails.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import { database } from "../../../firebase";
import ViewImageFileModal from "../../modals/multimediaModals/view/ViewImageFileModal";

/**
 * It's a component that displays audio, video, and image files
 * @param props - The props object that is passed to the component.
 * @returns The MultimediaDetails component is being returned.
 */
const MultimediaDetails = (props) => {
    /* Destructuring the props object. */
    const { pId } = props;

    /* Setting the state of the component. */
    const [imageData, setImageData] = useState([]);
    const [imageMessage, setImageMessage] = useState(true);
    const userType = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("admin") ?? false);

    // Modal Variables
    const [showViewImageModal, setShowViewImageModal] = useState(false);
    const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(Object);

    /**
     * When the user clicks on the audio, video, or image file, the file data is set and the modal is
     * toggled.
     * @param obj
     */

    const viewImageFile = (obj) => {
        setFileData(obj);
        toggleViewImageModal();
    };

    /* The function to toggle modal states */
    const toggleAddImageModal = () => setShowAddImageModal((p) => !p);
    const toggleViewImageModal = () => setShowViewImageModal((p) => !p);

    useEffect(() => {
        /* Query data from database and listening for changes. */
        const imageQuery = database.portfolioRef.doc(pId).collection("images");


        const unsubscribeImage = imageQuery.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.docs.length !== 0) {
                setImageMessage(false);
                setImageData(
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
                );
            } else {
                setImageMessage(true);
            }
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribeImage();
        };
    }, [pId]);

    return (
        <div className="multimedia-section">
            <div id="image-section">
                <div id="image-header">
                    <h6>
                        <u>Images</u>
                    </h6>
                    {userType ? (
                        <button className="addbtn" onClick={() => toggleAddImageModal()}>
                            <AiIcons.AiOutlinePlus /> Add Image File
                        </button>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div id="image-content" className="multimedia-flex">
                    {imageMessage ? (
                        <p>There is not existing images for this portfolio.</p>
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            {imageData.map((doc) => (
                                <button
                                    key={doc.id}
                                    className="fileBtn"
                                    onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc)}
                                >
                                    <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
                                </button>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
            <ViewImageFileModal
                show={showViewImageModal}
                toggleModal={toggleViewImageModal}
                pId={pId}
                data={fileData}
                key={fileData.id}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MultimediaDetails;
```

The initialised values for the Modal.

```
    /* Setting the initial state of the component. */
    const valueState = {
        name: '',
        description: ''
    }
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [formStateDisabled, setFormStateDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [deleteState, setDeleteState] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");
    const [loadForm, setLoadForm] = useState(false)
    const [view, setView] = useState(false);

    /* Destructuring the props object. */
    const { show, toggleModal } = props;
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors, loading } =
        useForm(validateUpdate, valueState, handleUpdate);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(props.data).length !== 0) {
            values.name = props.data.imageName;
            values.description = props.data.imageDesc;
            setLoadForm(true);
        }
    }, [])
```

The warning I get ***(Shown Below)***, each time I click on the modal button to open the button, I noticed the warning actually repeats twice, and when I close it, it repeats another 2 times making it 4. I am not sure what is the cause of this, please help! Thank you!

### [image: warning]

Updates of trials
I only have 4 rows of data, all of which has its own unique id. Therefore I am unsure of where the duplicated key came from. However, if I remove the modal key "fileData.id" this warning would disappear. However, my component state will not reset and there will be a lot of props data issue that would surface. Where data for the previously clicked button will appear on the another button. Or the data might not appear at all.

[image: update]

FOR ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
This is the output for the map buttons
[image: sample]

I don't see any duplicates, and I am not sure where the issue is. Is there something I am doing wrong to cause this error.  I checked my DB there isn't any data error as well.

Comment: You have a bunch of `<div>` with a shared parent. Try adding a `key=` attribute on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrap my model with a condition if imageId exist and it works already!

```
{imageId !== '' && 
      <ViewImageFileModal 
          show={showViewImageModal} 
          toggleModal={toggleViewImageModal} 
          imageData={imageData} 
          key={imageId} 
      />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Recommended solution

The problem is that your `doc.id` is repeating.

You are setting the imageData at the `imageQuery.onSnapshot` callback function, when you run the following code:

```
setImageData(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
```

What you need to make sure is that `doc.id` is unique in this context (because you're using this value at the key attribute in your buttons).

**That's the correct way to fix it**.

## Alternative solution

Another way to handle it (as a last resort), is using the following code, where you use the `index` position of the element at the `key` attribute:

```
{imageData.map((doc, index) => (
    <button
        key={index}
        className="fileBtn"
        onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc)}
    >
        <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
    </button>
))}
```

But this is not recommended according to the React documentation:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
> change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
> with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
> [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).
> If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
> React will default to using indexes as keys.
>
> Here is an [in-depth explanation about why keys are necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) if you’re
> interested in learning more.

Comment: Hi @leonardomdr, I tried making it unique, as firebase IDs are unique. but I'm not sure what is the issue here. I believe the issue is more towards the modal key instead. I will edit the question which what I have tried for you to take a look

Comment: I Added a sample picture of the button output in my question. I dont see any duplicates. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: @der, it's hard to tell. I suggest you create a js fiddle mocking this situation, so anyone can try and test this locally as well. Also, I believe that you don't need to set `key` attribute in your `ViewImageFileModal` component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **doc.id** use map item index like bellow. See if it works.

```
{imageData.map((index, doc) => (
   <button
      key={index}
          className="fileBtn"
            onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc)}>
                <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
   </button>
))}
```

Comment: Hi @Ebrahim Khalil Amid, I have tried this but it doesn't work. I feel the main culprit is the key at the view modal

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit:

```
{imageData.map((doc) => (
    <button
        key={doc.id}
        className="fileBtn"
        onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc)}
    >
        <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
    </button>
))}
```

The main issue here is that doc.id is duplicate, probably you have duplicate data in your `imageData` or ou have a faulty data in your database or something that generate a non-unique id.

To easily fix the issue, what you can do is use index of map.

```
{imageData.map((doc, index) => (
    <button
        key={index}
        className="fileBtn"
        onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc)}
    >
        <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
    </button>
))}
```

`index` are always unique. but I suggest you should fix and see why you have duplicate data instead of just bypassing it with an index.

### **UPDATE**

This is quite a hacky solution, but since I can't really pin point what's causing the issue without investigating first hand, let's make it so you don't have to pass a `key` on the modal.

So instead of storing the object data on the state, store the id instead:

Rename `fileData` to `fileDataId`.

```
 const [fileDataId, setFileDataId] = useState(0);
```

then store the id when clicking the button.

```
{imageData.map((doc) => (
    <button
        key={doc.id}
        className="fileBtn"
        onClick={() => viewImageFile(doc.id)}
    >
        <FaIcons.FaImage /> {doc.imageName}
    </button>
))}
```

on the Modal, you have to pass the `imageData` and the selected id, then remove the `key`:

```
<ViewImageFileModal
    show={showViewImageModal}
    toggleModal={toggleViewImageModal}
    pId={pId}
    list={imageData}
    selectedId={fileDataId}
/>
```

then inside `ViewImageFileModal` you can declare data as:

```
const data= props.list.find(image => image.id === props.selectedId);
```

Comment: Hi @I am L, the problem didn't occur with this being the key for the buttons. It occur only when I add "key={fileData.id}" to the view Modal. Additionally, I tried removing the Key for this view button as well and the warning still persist. Therefore, I feel the culprit to the warning is not the button but the modal key instead.

Comment: I tried doing key={doc.id + index}, I still get the same warning

Comment: @der I have updated my answer, can you check it?

Comment: Hi @IamL, I did accordingly to your update, and still came out with the same error. but I tried this and it worked! I just wrap my model with a condition if imageId exist.{imageId !== '' &&
                <ViewImageFileModal
                    show={showViewImageModal}
                    toggleModal={toggleViewImageModal}
                    imageData={imageData}
                    selectedId={imageId}
                    key={imageId}
                />}